# upgrade vb6 project using msdxm.ocx to wmp.dll

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-media-player

We have a legacy vb6 application that uses an ancient windows media player component, `msdxm.ocx`, to embed ultrasound (pregnancy) video's in the medical record.

This doesn't work any more on Windows 7: it has a newer version of `msdxm.ocx` which cannot be referenced from vb6.

The newer version of the embeddable player is `wmp.dll`, so we are planning to upgrade the application to the newer version for Windows 7.

Before we have to find it all out the hard way by ourselves: does someone have experience with this upgrade from `msdxm.ocx` to `wpm.dll`? Is there a list of things to consider when upgrading? Or a table to convert constants and events from the first to the second?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything listing their object models side-by-side or offering any "conversion."

The msdxm.ocx was really a scriptable IE object and should not have been used in VB6 programs.  Lots of people did though.  Windows 7 still has this OCX but starting with Vista (or perhaps IE7?) its interfaces changed in a way that seems to prevent use in VB6 programs.

You might want to try running a tool like [ActiveX Documenter](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/utilities/ActiveX_Documenter/article.asp) aginst working versions of both libraries to assist your efforts though.  The RTF output documents might be a starting point for writing your own conversion guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping someone has documented his/her efforts in the past, but it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 0):

msdxm.ocx should still work if you put the OCX file in **C:\Windows\SysWOW64** and register it.

I've tried on my Win7 and it works on my music player legacy app.

Don't know about Windows 8 though, but it might still be the same, MS might changed folder again then.